# Eigenspace of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ be defined as follow:
>
> 1. $T\left(6\,x^2-x+2 \right )=30\,x^2+10\,x+43$
> 2. $T\left(5\,x+3 \right )=20\,x+12$
> 3. $T\left(5\,x-1 \right )=24\,x^2+x+31$
>
> Basis $B=\left \{ 6\,x^2-x+2, 5\,x+3, 5\,x-1 \right \}$
>
> Find $[T]_b$ and the basis  of the corresponding eigenvector $\lambda=1$, as a vectors of the given vector space (polynomial)

As for $[T]_b$ the way is to express the $T(v)$ as a linear combination of the given basis of $B$ which result:

$$[T]_b=\begin{pmatrix}
    5       & 0 &4 \\
   9& 4 &6 \\
   -6       &0 & -5
\end{pmatrix}$$

So for the given $\lambda=1$ we get: $$A_{\lambda}=\begin{pmatrix}
    4       & 0 &4 \\
   9& 3 &6 \\
   -6       &0 & -6
\end{pmatrix} \sim  \begin{pmatrix}
    1       & 0 &1 \\
   0& 1 &-1 \\
   0      &0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

So the eigenspace coordinates is $$Span\begin{pmatrix}
    -1      \\
   -1 \\
   1 
\end{pmatrix} $$

How should I continue?

Comment: And what is $V$, if you please?

Comment: @Bernard sorry, edited

Comment: Does $[T]_b$ denote the matrix of $T$ in basis $\mathcal B$?

Comment: @Bernard yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small error in computing the eigenspace which is
$$Span\begin{pmatrix}
    -1      \\
   1 \\
   1 
\end{pmatrix} $$ After that you're almost done as you can say that an eigenvector is $$-(6x^2-x+2)+(5x+3)+(5x-1)=-6x^2+11x$$ multiplied by a real.

Answer (score 1):

To compute $[T]_b$, I would start from the fact we know the matrix of $T\colon(V,\mathcal B)\to (T,\mathcal C)$, where $\mathcal C$ denotes the canonical basis $(1,x,x^2)$:
$$T_{\mathcal{C,\,B}}=\begin{bmatrix}
6&0&0\\10&20&1\\43&12&31
\end{bmatrix}$$
Let $\;P_{\mathcal{C,\,B}}=\begin{bmatrix}
30&0&24\\-1&5&5\\2&3&-1
\end{bmatrix}$ the change of basis matrix from the canonical basis to basis $\mathcal B$. We have:
$$T_{\mathcal{B,\,B}}=P_{\mathcal{B,\,C}}\,T_{\mathcal{C,\,B}}=P_{\mathcal{C,\,B}}^{-1}\,T_{\mathcal{B,\,C}}=\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{-}5&0&\hphantom{-}4\\-\dfrac94&\dfrac14&-\dfrac32\\-6&0&-5
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: How do we know that $C$ is the canonical basis?

Comment: Because the images of the vectors of $\mathcal B$ are expressed in the canonical basis (linear combinations of $1,x,x^2$).